# MySQL Sub select multiple condition

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery

I'm trying to combine multiple select statements into 1 query but can't seem to get it right. I figure I would need to do a sub select.  I'm sure it's something simple I'm overlooking.  I have more after the 2nd query but they're all the same setup except different TAS_UID numbers.

Query 1:

```
SELECT USR_USERNAME AS 'User Name', 
           COUNT(AD.app_uid) AS 'Total'
FROM   APP_DELEGATION AD
JOIN   USERS U
WHERE  AD.USR_UID = U.USR_UID
AND    AD.DEL_THREAD_STATUS = 'Closed'
GROUP BY AD.USR_UID
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT USR_USERNAME AS 'User Name', 
       COUNT(AD.app_uid) AS 'Total for Task A'
FROM   APP_DELEGATION AD
JOIN   USERS U
WHERE  AD.USR_UID = U.USR_UID
AND    AD.DEL_THREAD_STATUS = 'Closed'
AND    AD.TAS_UID = '23423423455'
GROUP BY AD.USR_UID
```

Comment: what do you want your result to look like?  Your 2nd query appears to be just a subset of your first.

Comment: @nycdan Result should display as follows: 1st column: user names, 2nd column: count of all taks, column 3: count of only specified task uid

Comment: okay, I added an answer that I think will help.  My syntax might be slightly off, but it should get you there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do that with a Case statement.  Something like this:

```
SELECT USR_USERNAME AS 'User Name'
  ,COUNT(AD.app_uid) AS 'Total'
  ,SUM(case when AD.TAS_UID = '23423423455' then 1 else 0 end) as 'Total for Task A'
FROM APP_DELEGATION AS AD
  JOIN USERS AS U 
  ON AD.USR_UID = U.USR_UID
WHERE AD.DEL_THREAD_STATUS = 'Closed'
GROUP BY AD.USR_USERNAME
```

Comment: wouldn't you need to remove the WHERE AND statement as it was already stated in the sum function? Also, what exactly is the case then 1 else 0 doing?

Comment: You are correct.  The AND should come out.  I will edit accordingly.  Thanks.  The case statement adds up the number of rows that meet the criteria.  It's basically a count.

Comment: ah that would make sense.  Kinda got what else 0 was doing but was unsure of the 1.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your queries are not correct.  They should probably be something like the following:

***Query 1:***

```
SELECT USR_USERNAME AS 'User Name', COUNT(AD.app_uid) AS 'Total'
FROM APP_DELEGATION AS AD
  JOIN USERS AS U 
  ON AD.USR_UID = U.USR_UID
WHERE AD.DEL_THREAD_STATUS = 'Closed'
GROUP BY AD.USR_UID
```

***Query 2:***

```
SELECT USR_USERNAME AS 'User Name', COUNT(AD.app_uid) AS 'Total for Task A'
FROM APP_DELEGATION AS AD
  JOIN USERS AS U 
  ON AD.USR_UID = U.USR_UID
WHERE AD.DEL_THREAD_STATUS = 'Closed'
  AND AD.TAS_UID = '23423423455'
GROUP BY AD.USR_UID
```

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem or are you still in need of something further?